# Expressing an angle outside of a circle in terms of an angle inside of a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

A question in textbook says that in a circle, $BN$ is a diameter, $BONC$ and $AMC$ are straight lines.
If $MC = OB$, prove that $\angle ABC + \frac{3}{2}\angle ACB = 90^\circ$ .

Drawn diagram which might not be correct:

[image: diagram]

It is apparent that $\angle ABC + \angle ANB = 90^\circ$, so this leaves the question of why $\angle ANB = \frac{3}{2}\angle ACB$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is because $\angle NAM = 0.5 \angle NOM$.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance Mick!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\angle NOM=\alpha$. Then $\angle NAM=\alpha/2$, because $NAM$ is inscribed angle based on an arc $NM$. From triangle $CAN$ we have that $\angle CNA=180^{\circ}-3\alpha/2$ and hence $\angle ANB=3\alpha/2$.

Comment: I see, I completely overlooked this part, thank you very much greyls!